# How do I create an NSArray with string literals?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

I'm attempting to create an NSArray with a grouping of string literals, however I get the compile error "Initializer element is not constant".

```
NSArray *currencies = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Dollar", @"Euro", @"Pound", nil];
```

Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong, and possibly explain the error message?

Comment: Your code should work, are you sure the error isn't elsewhere?

Comment: You should say where you have put that line because it sounds like you didn't put it in a method.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This isn't a problem with the NSArray creation itself (you would get the same error if you wrote `[NSArray array]` instead), but with where you've written it. I'm guessing this is a global or file-static NSArray. In C, that kind of variable has to have a constant initializer — meaning not a function call (or, by extension, a method call). The solution is to put the actual creation and assignment of the array into a method that will be called before you need the array, such as `initialize`.

Comment: I had declared this in the header file, but was unaware that I could not initialize this outside of a method.

Comment: would it be safe to put it inside `+load`?

Answer (score 76):

New syntax for creating an array with string literals:

```
NSArray *currencies = @[@"Dollar", @"Euro", @"Pound"];
```

To fix your complication error the code must be in a method. If you want to use it statically then create a class method that follows the singleton pattern.

Comment: Worth to notice it's going to be dynamically allocated array if it's inside of the method. I expected it to be as static constant array.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like Chuck has spotted the problem. One thing you want to be aware of though in coding your solution is that you'll want to avoid storing an autoreleased instance of NSArray in a static variable. Also, a common pattern for these situations is to write a class method that creates and returns the value stored in the static variable, like so:

```
+ (NSArray *)currencies
{
    static NSArray *_currencies;

    // This will only be true the first time the method is called...
    //
    if (_currencies == nil)
    {
        _currencies = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Dollar", @"Euro", @"Pound", nil];
    }

    return _currencies;
}
```

Comment: Hi, why is it not recommended to store autoreleased objects in static variables? Is it for efficiency so that they are not asked their retain count on every loop?

Comment: Objects in an autorelease pool aren't asked for their retain count; they're sent a `release` message when the autorelease pool is released. If an autoreleased object is stored in a static variable, the variable will contain an invalid address once this happens, and attempts to reference it will either crash your program, or even worse, cause it to incorrectly access some newer object that's been allocated at that address in the interim.

Comment: Yes this is true, the docs also state that if you retain an autorelease object, your object will not be deallocated when the pool gets drained. If you use appkit an autorelease pool will be created on each event loop and drained at the end of it. So I think it does call retain count.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is old, please notice that Apple committed a new patch to the llvm project adding support for new Objective-C literal syntax for `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` and `NSNumber`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347722/apple-llvm-4-0-new-features-on-xcode-4-4-literals) and [here](http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2012/03/13/new-objectivec-literal-syntax/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a newbie in objective-c, but I think that the correct code is:

> NSArray *currencies = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Dollar", @"Euro", @"Pound", nil];

I am not sure tho.

Comment: That is also valid, however there is nothing wrong with OP's code. Your method simply retains the array whereas his does not

Comment: However, if the object stored in a static variable is **not** retained, it's a lurking crasher bug, so alloc/init would be the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with that code.  Are you sure the error is being produced at that line?